# Развернуть Telegram Бота на Heroku

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, heroku

Как развернуть Telegram бота написанного на Python на Heroku?

UPD

Залил я бота. Но он не работает...

Вот полный код бота:

```
import telebot
import config
import time
import vk

array = [None]
bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

def posting():
    try:
        vk_api = vk.API(vk.AuthSession(app_id = 6087806 , user_login = '***', user_password = '***'))
        while True:
            post = vk_api.wall.get(owner_id=-45745333, count=1, offset=1)[1]
            if post['marked_as_ads'] == 0 and post['attachment']['type'] == 'photo' and post['id'] != array[0]:
                array[0] = post['id']
                bot.send_photo('@***', vk_api.wall.get(owner_id=-45745333, count=1, offset=1)[1]['attachment']['photo']['src_big'])
                time.sleep(2)
    except Exception as e:
        posting()
posting()
```

В `config.py`:

```
# coding: utf8
token = '***'
```

Ввожу `heroku ps:scale web=1`, получаю:

```
Scaling dynos... done, now running web at 1:Free
```

В логах:

```
2017-07-14T18:00:21.440124+00:00 app[web.1]:     import telebot
2017-07-14T18:00:21.440128+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telebot'
```

Как его туда установить?

Comment: Почитайте документацию - там подробно описано. Учтите, что на бесплатном уровне ваш сервер будут регулярно выключать.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman обновил вопрос

Comment: знаете, что такое менеджер зависимостей?

Answer (score 2):

Привет! Тоже ботов пишу, ты на хероку requirements.txt заливал? У тебя проблема не в коде,а в подключаемых библиотеках

**Создание requirements.txt**

Создаешь в глав.директории своего бота пустой фай с именем requirements.txt, открываешь через любой редактор и кидаешь туда все либы, которые подключил, вот к примеру мой:

```
requests==2.7.0

telebot==0.0.3

CherryPy==10.2.2
```

Узнать название и версии либ можно консольной командой `pip freeze` ну или для удобства выгрузи куда-нибудь их `pip freeze > C:\libs.txt`

Правда он выкидывает абсолютно все либы, так что придется повытаскивать нужное

Comment: Да, именно :( 
Сейчас исправлю

Comment: Не проще в virtualenw это делать? pip'ом установил, установил зависимости. Профит

Comment: @Alban на heroku-то? Нет, не проще.